# Change front page url by keeping its content

Tags: 7

I would like to change front page url to some string, e.g. http://example.com/pattern and need all `url('<front>')` links to be changed to the new url and 301 redirect to new url after openening the site directly as well.

Comment: Is this a Drupal 7 question?

Comment: Where's your frontpage content coming from?

Comment: I'm collecting information from verios views and in page--front.tpl.php

Answer (score 1):

You simple need to configure that in your website settings:

Configuration >> System >> Site information

There you will find the "Front page" panel where you can enter your new front page URL.

Cheers!

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that the OP should update the path of wherever the content of the frontpage is coming from as well. If it's views, then update the path there, and if it's a ctools panel page, then update the path there too.

Answer (score 1):

A different answer:

You can use the [Front Page](https://www.drupal.org/project/front) module to do this, for both setting the frontpage URL as well as getting url('') to work as you want.

After you install the module, navigate to Configuration >> Front Page >> Home links and enter the pattern you want to use.

Curious to see if that worked for you!

Comment: Good module but it handles my problem particularly as far as when I create new alias for home, `url('<front>')` works fine but after putting redirect option to my new url, the module creates unlimited redirections. Thanks anyway.